# Objc - how to add a video player inside a UIView like this?

Tags: objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, video-player

This player only have 2 buttons,play/pause and fullscreen,it looks like a `system player`,so fast and simple.

I used `UIWebView and HTML5` inside the UIView,but UIWebView is so slow and can not play without fullscreen.

If this player is a `UIObject` or some UIView things,how can I add it?

thanks~

[image: sample video player in app Everyday.me]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a video player into your `UIView` using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Here is Apple sample code which does just like this.
It can stream a video from internet as well as play a local movie file.

You can change the playback controls by changing the moviePlayer `controlStyle` property.

You can find the sample code from the link below

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thank you viktoR,I got it with `MPMoviePlayerController`,but still have a problem,when my view with video push another view,the video could not stop and sound playing.

Comment: @yellow, before you push another view, stop `MPMoviePlayerController`,
`[myMoviePlayer stop]` will do the trick.
Or if you just want to pause the video, you can use `[myMoviePlayer pause]` .
Go through `MPMoviePlayerController` class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 13):

The MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated from iOS 9.
You can insert a video into iOS project with AVPlayerViewController now.

For example:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *stringVideoName = @"video.m4v";
    NSString *stringVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:stringVideoName ofType:nil];
    NSAssert(stringVideoPath, @"Expected not nil video file");

    NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringVideoPath];
    NSAssert(urlVideoFile, @"Expected not nil video url");

    _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];
    _playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

}
```

Comment: just copied and pasted, and it works great. thanks a lot

Comment: I need to play youtube url so I write my nsurl in urlVideoFile. but noting is displaying on my view. 
pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Improts Following frameworks

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Add following code in UIView Or UIViewController Class
`videoView` is UIView

```
    // Url of Video
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlOfVideo"];

    // Init Player
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];

    // Add Player in AVPlayerViewController
    playerViewController.player = player;
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true;

    // Set Frame accoding to view
    playerViewController.view.frame = _videoView.bounds;

    //Used to Play On start
    [playerViewController.player play];

    // Add Video in UIView
    [_videoView addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

I hope it will work for you...